# How to fix brackets in a Java program?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm having trouble with the brackets, am I doing something wrong. Everything I add a bracket somewhere trying to fix the errors, its either says I need an `elseStatment` or I need to add another bracket and when I add that other bracket, I get one great big error saying "Unreachable Code."

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain why this happens and help me fix it. To show you where the errors are happening I will put 3 exclamation marks.

```
package me.bukkit.Ragnarok;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerSelector;

public class StandardFlight extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("StandardFlight: Flight plugin has been loaded successfully!");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() { 

    } **!!!**

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("flight") && sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            if(player.hasPermission("uheal.heal.self")) {

            if (args.length == 0) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Ops, try " + ChatColor.RED + "/flight on " + ChatColor.GOLD + "or " + ChatColor.RED + "/flight off");
            return true;

            if (args.length == 1) {
            } else  if (args[0].equals("on")) {
                player.setAllowFlight(true);
                player.setFlying(true);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Setting Flight for player: " + ChatColor.RED + player.getName() + ChatColor.GOLD + ChatColor.BOLD + " On!");
                return true;

                if (args.length == 1) {
            } else if (args[0].equals("off")) {
                    player.setAllowFlight(false);
                    player.setFlying(false);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Setting Flight for player: " + ChatColor.RED + player.getName() + ChatColor.GOLD + ChatColor.BOLD + " Off!");  
                    return true;

            }
            return false;

        }
        {

    }

    }

} **!!!**
```

Comment: you should clean up your indenting. You're all over the place with that. Once you have your code PROPERLY indendent, the bracketing should become VISUALLY obvious.

Comment: Also, your ifs make no sense?

Comment: Its the one at the bottom messing everything up you have return false;}{}}} also at the top the first if has no close brace after return true; This should be obvious if you are using an IDE Check out code Format if you are using an ide to see the problems you have, for instance any code after a return is inaccessible

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
     player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Ops, try " + ChatColor.RED + "/flight on " + ChatColor.GOLD + "or " + ChatColor.RED + "/flight off");
     return true;

     if (args.length == 1) {
```

Note the indendetation. This code block can ONLY execute if `args.length` is 0, which means that the `args.length == 1` can **NEVER** be true. And since you `return` unconditionally before that second if, there's your "unreachable code".

So.. you're probably missing a `}` right there:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Ops, try " + ChatColor.RED + "/flight on " + ChatColor.GOLD + "or " + ChatColor.RED + "/flight off");
    return true;
} else if (args.length == 1) {
^^^^^^^^^^---NOTE THIS
```

If you had taken the time to properly format your code, this should have become obvious.

Comment: Also note that `Unreachable Statement` is reported because the code returns so all other code is not executed and is thus unreachable.

Comment: The next missing close bracket is for `else  if (args[0].equals("on")) {`

Comment: Oh, i see now, yes that helped, but now im getting this "Unreachable Code," part. Its near the end at the: } else if (args[0].equals("off")) {

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues, but here is what I came up with that has the  proper brackets, at least I think they are based on what I assume you are trying to do:

```
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerSelector;

public class StandardFlight extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("StandardFlight: Flight plugin has been loaded successfully!");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() { 

    } **!!!**

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("flight") && sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            if(player.hasPermission("uheal.heal.self")) {

            if (args.length == 0) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Ops, try " + ChatColor.RED + "/flight on " + ChatColor.GOLD + "or " + ChatColor.RED + "/flight off");
                return true;
            }
            if (args.length == 1) {

            } else  if (args[0].equals("on")) {
                player.setAllowFlight(true);
                player.setFlying(true);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Setting Flight for player: " + ChatColor.RED + player.getName() + ChatColor.GOLD + ChatColor.BOLD + " On!");
                return true;
                //This code is unreachable because you have a return statement above it. You need to move the code below it. 
                if (args.length == 1) {

                } else if (args[0].equals("off")) {
                    player.setAllowFlight(false);
                    player.setFlying(false);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Setting Flight for player: " + ChatColor.RED + player.getName() + ChatColor.GOLD + ChatColor.BOLD + " Off!");  
                    return true;

            }
            return false;

        }
    }
}

}

} **!!!**
```

Comment: It fixed most of the bracket issuies, but not i have a section where it says, "Unreachable Code." Right around here:
  } else if (args[0].equals("off")) {
                    player.setAllowFlight(false);
                    player.setFlying(false);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Setting Flight for player: " + ChatColor.RED + player.getName() + ChatColor.GOLD + ChatColor.BOLD + " Off!");  
                    return true;

Comment: @Ragnarok I updated teh code with a comment. You have a return statement, then code beneath it. All the code beneath it is unreachable because you return it. Move that code or the return statement.

Comment: Alright, well, now it still has the damn Unreachable Code thing. I hate that error so much. Do you have any ideas of what i should do for that? @BlackHatSamurai

Comment: I think you should format your code, line up your brackets properly, and the walk through the code. You have a number of return statements that could be causing that issue. You need to get everything lined up so you can see what you are doing.

Comment: Alright, will do. Sorry, i'm a pretty new beginner, i'm trying just to not get any errors so i can export and test it...

Comment: Format your code. When it is easy to read, you can figure out what is going on. I don't know why else you are getting that error, but it probably has to do with one of your return statements. But I don't know. Good luck.